# Multiple checkbox filtering in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, react-hooks, material-ui

I'm struggling to create multiple Checkbox filtering in React with Material-UI. The difficult is that checkbox options are created dynamically from received data  and should be split by each type of Select components

But I can't properly create states to manage them in the App.

Any ideas how to do it correctly?

Options Component

```
function filterDuplicate(arr) {
  return arr.filter((elem, index, array) => array.indexOf(elem) === index);
}

export default function Options({ stat }) {
  const [form, setForm] = useState({
    publicationType: "",
    termType: "",
    reportGroup: "",
    reportState: "",
    reportFormat: ""
  });

  const publicationTypes = filterDuplicate(
    stat.map((data) => data.publicationType)
  );
  const termTypes = filterDuplicate(stat.map((data) => data.termType));
  const reportGroups = filterDuplicate(stat.map((data) => data.reportGroup));
  const reportStates = filterDuplicate(stat.map((data) => data.reportState));
  const reportFormats = filterDuplicate(stat.map((data) => data.reportFormat));

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(form);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="options">
        <Select type="Publication type" options={publicationTypes} />
        <Select type="Term type" options={termTypes} />
        <Select type="Report group" options={reportGroups} />
        <Select type="Status" options={reportStates} />
        <Select type="File Type" options={reportFormats} />
        <Button variant="contained" color="secondary" type="submit">
          RESET
        </Button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
}

Options.propTypes = {
  stat: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({})).isRequired
};
```

Select Component

```
export default function Select({ type, options }) {
  const [check, setCheck] = useState([]);
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  const classes = useStyles();

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    if (e.target.checked) {
      setCheck([...check, e.target.value]);
    } else {
      setCheck(check.filter((id) => id !== e.target.value));
    }
    const str = check.join(", ");
    setValue(str);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
        <InputLabel id="select-label" className={classes.label}>
          {type}
        </InputLabel>
        <MaterialSelect labelId="select-label" id="input-select">
          {options.map((option) => (
            <Checkbox option={option} key={option} onChange={handleChange} />
          ))}
        </MaterialSelect>
      </FormControl>
    </>
  );
}
```

Checkbox Component

```
const Checkbox = React.forwardRef(({ option, onChange }, ref) => {
  return (
    <div ref={ref}>
      <FormControlLabel
        control={<MaterialCheckbox onChange={onChange} color="primary" />}
        label={option}
        value={option}
      />
    </div>
  );
});

Checkbox.propTypes = {
  option: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default Checkbox;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/checkbox-filter-vqex7?file=/src/Options.js:0-1593

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you only pass data from parent to child. On App.js they are two separate components. You should write a function on App.js that connects these two components.

Your App.js

```
export default function App() {
  const [stat, setState] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setState(data);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <div>
          <h1>Information</h1>
        </div>
        <Options stat={stat} />
        <Data info={stat} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

App.js when filtering method added

```
export default function App() {
  const [stat, setState] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setState(data);
  }, []);
  const handleFilter = (selectedValue) => {
    console.log(selectedValue);
   //apply filtering here and setState again
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <div>
          <h1>Information</h1>
        </div>
        <Options stat={stat} handleFilter={handleFilter} />
        <Data info={stat} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Options.js

```
export default function Options({ stat, handleFilter }) {
  const [form, setForm] = useState({
    publicationType: "",
    termType: "",
    reportGroup: "",
    reportState: "",
    reportFormat: ""
  });

  const publicationTypes = filterDuplicate(
    stat.map((data) => data.publicationType)
  );
  const termTypes = filterDuplicate(stat.map((data) => data.termType));
  const reportGroups = filterDuplicate(stat.map((data) => data.reportGroup));
  const reportStates = filterDuplicate(stat.map((data) => data.reportState));
  const reportFormats = filterDuplicate(stat.map((data) => data.reportFormat));

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(form);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="options">
        <Select
          type="Publication type"
          options={publicationTypes}
          handleFilter={handleFilter}
        />
        <Select
          type="Term type"
          options={termTypes}
          handleFilter={handleFilter}
        />
        <Select
          type="Report group"
          options={reportGroups}
          handleFilter={handleFilter}
        />
        <Select
          type="Status"
          options={reportStates}
          handleFilter={handleFilter}
        />
        <Select
          type="File Type"
          options={reportFormats}
          handleFilter={handleFilter}
        />
        <Button variant="contained" color="secondary" type="submit">
          RESET
        </Button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
}
```

Select.js

```
export default function Select({ type, options, handleFilter }) {
  const [check, setCheck] = useState([]);
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  const classes = useStyles();

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    if (e.target.checked) {
      handleFilter(e.target.value);
      setCheck([...check, e.target.value]);
    } else {
      setCheck(check.filter((id) => id !== e.target.value));
    }
    const str = check.join(", ");
    setValue(str);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
        <InputLabel id="select-label" className={classes.label}>
          {type}
        </InputLabel>
        <MaterialSelect labelId="select-label" id="input-select">
          {options.map((option) => (
            <Checkbox option={option} key={option} onChange={handleChange} />
          ))}
        </MaterialSelect>
      </FormControl>
    </>
  );
}
```

With that structure, you can receive checked value on App.js and filter data.

Comment: The issue is that I don't know how to correctly handle states in checkbox component. How should I write them so then I can pass them to filter function?

Comment: I have controlled the checkbox component and it works in the same way I've provided above. **Child to parent data passing** If you run the code above you will see the live checked results on the console. Anyways, maybe you would like to look for an easier and faster solution with react tables. [link](https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/examples/filtering)